# Get Trend/Streak in Each Row of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 0.1, 2.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.3],
                   ['B', -0.3, -0.4, 0.1, 0.2, -1.0],
                   ['C', 0.1, -1.0, 4.0, -3.3, 1.0],
                   ['D', -0.1, -1.0, -4.0, -3.3, -1.0],
                   ['E', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   ['F', 4.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
                  ], columns=['Group', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])


  Group    1    2    3    4    5  
0     A  0.1  2.0  1.0  0.5  0.3  
1     B -0.3 -0.4  0.1  0.2 -1.0  
2     C  0.1 -1.0  4.0 -3.3  1.0  
3     D -0.1 -1.0 -4.0 -3.3 -1.0  
4     E  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
5     F  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

For each row, I'd like to return the trend/streak of either consecutive positive/negative values going from left to right. So, the final DataFrame should be:

```
  Group    1    2    3    4    5  Streak  
0     A  0.1  2.0  1.0  0.5  0.3       5   
1     B -0.3 -0.4  0.1  0.2 -1.0      -2   
2     C  0.1 -1.0  4.0 -3.3  1.0       1   
3     D -0.1 -1.0 -4.0 -3.3 -1.0      -5   
4     E  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       0    
5     F  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       1
```

The first row has a streak of +5 because the values are all positive going from left to right. The second row has a streak of negative -2 because the first two columns have negative values and the streak ends with a positive value in column 3. The third row has a streak of +1 because the second column has an opposite sign from the first column. The fourth row is all NaN and so the streak is zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long-winded, but it seems to do everything you need:

```
def streak(row):

    cols = row.keys()    
    n_cols = len(cols)

    neg_streak = 0
    pos_streak = 0
    i_neg_streak = n_cols
    i_pos_streak = n_cols

    for icol_1 in range(n_cols - 1):
        for icol_2 in range(icol_1, n_cols):
            if (row.ix[icol_1: icol_2 + 1] < 0).all():
                streak = icol_1 - icol_2 - 1
                if streak < neg_streak:
                    neg_streak = streak
                    i_neg_streak = icol_1
            elif (row.ix[icol_1: icol_2 + 1] > 0).all():
                streak = 1 + icol_2 - icol_1
                if streak > pos_streak:
                    pos_streak = streak
                    i_pos_streak = icol_1

    if pos_streak == abs(neg_streak):
        if i_pos_streak < i_neg_streak:
            return pos_streak
        else:
            return neg_streak
    elif pos_streak > abs(neg_streak):
        return pos_streak
    else:
        return neg_streak

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 0.1, 2.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.3],
                   ['B', -0.3, -0.4, 0.1, 0.2, -1.0],
                   ['C', 0.1, -1.0, 4.0, -3.3, 1.0]
                   ], columns=['Group', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])

df = df.set_index('Group')
df['Streak'] = df.apply(lambda row: streak(row), axis = 1)
df = df.reset_index()

print df
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the longest streak.  **Can't make any promises about ties...**  This answer uses [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).  First, under the hood so you can see what groupby is doing:

```
In [4]: b = [-0.3, -0.4, 0.1, 0.2, -1.0]
        for k,g in groupby(b, key=lambda x: x > 0.0):
           print k,list(g)

False [-0.3, -0.4]
True [0.1, 0.2]
False [-1.0]
```

Now wrap that in a function, taking advantage of the groupings:

```
def streak(dfrow):
    longest= 0
    for k,g in groupby(dfrow, key=lambda x: False if x<0 else True if x>0 else np.nan):
        cur_streak = len(list(g))
        if np.isnan(k):
            continue
        if k: #group is positive
            if abs(longest) < cur_streak:
                longest= cur_streak
        else: #group is negative
            if abs(longest) < cur_streak:
                longest= -1*cur_streak #multiply by -1
    return longest
```

Use `df.apply` to apply function to each row:

```
In [6]: df.set_index('Group',inplace=True)
        df['LongestStreak'] = df.apply(streak, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
In [281]: df
Out[281]:       1   2   3   4   5   LongestStreak
        Group                       
          A     0.1     2.0     1.0     0.5     0.3     5
          B     -0.3    -0.4    0.1     0.2     -1.0    -2
          C     0.1     -1.0    4.0     -3.3    1.0     1
```

***EDIT***

Updated to address your new DataFrame and added a benchmark, your's probably scales better, but I don't know how to modify your code to generate the results.

Results:

```
%%timeit
df['LongestStreak'] = df.apply(streak, axis=1)

1000 loops, best of 3: 473 µs per loop


%%timeit
a = (df[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']] >= 0).values # Get True/False values
diff = a[:, :-1] == a[:, 1:]
false_col = np.zeros((a.shape[0], 1), dtype=bool)  # Create a column of False
diff = np.concatenate((diff, false_col), axis=1)
df['Streak'] = np.argmin(diff, axis=1) + 1
df['Sign'] = df['1']
df['Sign'] = np.where(df['Sign'] > 0, 1, df['Sign'])
df['Sign'] = np.where(df['Sign'] < 0, -1, df['Sign'])
df['Sign'] = np.where(df['Sign'].isnull(), 0, df['Sign'])
df['Streak'] = df['Streak'] * df['Sign']
df['Streak'] = df['Streak'].astype(int)
df.drop('Sign', axis=1, inplace=True)

100 loops, best of 3: 2.94 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick and is more intuitive/vectorized

```
a = (df[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']] >= 0).values  # Get True/False values
diff = a[:, :-1] == a[:, 1:]  # Compare values from neighboring columns
```

So `diff` looks like this:

```
[[ True  True  True  True]
 [ True False  True False]
 [False False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True]]
```

Then,

```
false_col = np.zeros((a.shape[0], 1), dtype=bool)  # Create a column of False
diff = np.concatenate((diff, false_col), axis=1)  # Add False column to end of diff

[[ True  True  True  True False]
 [ True False  True False False]
 [False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False]]
```

Next, we look for streaks of `True` by looking for the first occurrence of `False`:

```
df['Streak'] = np.argmin(diff, axis=1) + 1  # Add 1 to the index get the streak
```

Finally, we adjust the sign of the streak value according to the sign of the first column:

```
df['Sign'] = df['1']
df['Sign'] = np.where(df['Sign'] > 0, 1, df['Sign'])
df['Sign'] = np.where(df['Sign'] < 0, -1, df['Sign'])
df['Sign'] = np.where(df['Sign'].isnull(), 0, df['Sign'])
df['Streak'] = df['Streak'] * df['Sign']
df['Streak'] = df['Streak'].astype(int)
df.drop('Sign', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

The final DataFrame looks like this:

```
  Group    1    2    3    4    5  Streak  
0     A  0.1  2.0  1.0  0.5  0.3       5  
1     B -0.3 -0.4  0.1  0.2 -1.0      -2  
2     C  0.1 -1.0  4.0 -3.3  1.0       1  
3     D -0.1 -1.0 -4.0 -3.3 -1.0      -5  
4     E  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       0  
5     F  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       1
```

Comment: Could you test your method on a larger DataFrame?  It'd be interesting to see the runtime difference between `apply` and your vectorized method. (and don't understand your code well enough yet to test it)